# Is there a way to get the Window Spotlight Wallpapers?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

When i was customizing the lock screen i noticed that when i changed from windows spotlight to picture than back to windows spotlight i got a different image. after doing this a couple of times i found this nice picture of what i could only describe as shot from inside a temple at night.

anyways i had that image for a few days but then when i went to lock my computer recently when i went to the toilet it changed (i didn't when i locked my computer earlier to go for a 30 minute walk)

i want to get it back so is there a way to get the Window Spotlight Wallpapers? preferably previous ones?

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth trying is getting the [SpotBright app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/spotbright/9nblggh5km22), and seeing if it downloads the picture that you are wanting. I can't find details on what pictures it will download; it seems to download whatever is currently cycling, so there's no guarantee that you will find the picture you want, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-save-all-windows-spotlight-lockscreen-images) is a tutorial for finding the downloaded Windows Spotlight images in your system files.  It's a bit of a lengthy process, though.  You can also peruse through the [Bing Homepage Gallery](https://www.bing.com/gallery/), which is where all those images come from.  They have thousands of great photos there, though not all are downloadable (it's the owner's choice).